# Determining a power amplifier's class

Tags: amplifier

How may I determine an amplifier's class given its schematic?

Based on the schematic I think it would be class F, but I am not sure.

Z elements are microstrips.

[image]

Comment: Class F means the MOSFET is switching on and off and, without knowledge of the input signal and all the impedances this cannot be confirmed or denied.

Comment: The weirdest part is the electrolytic cap C22, indicating that there it should be DC voltage, no RF.

Comment: @Andyaka are the microstrips' dimensions also required for you to be able to shed more light on this or merely the values of the various capacitors?